# How to show KeePass2 tray icon in Xfce

Tags: linux, debian, xfce, keepass

I am running KeePass2 under Debian and Xfce (via `mono`), which basically works fine. I know there is KeePassX for Linux, but I would rather stick to KeePass2. The only bug (?) I have found so far is that no system tray icon is shown.

Is there any way to fix this in Xfce?

Comment: KeePass uses the NotifyIcon class provided by the framework, thus this issue must be fixed in Mono (not KeePass). So plz wait.
You can see more here
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=590093
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14976

Answer (score 9):

You can install a plugin for KeePass2 to make it run with the indicator icon. First you need to add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dlech/+archive/ubuntu/keepass2-plugins):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dlech/keepass2-plugins
```

Then you need to update with the new PPA:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally install the plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install keepass2-plugin-application-indicator
```

From now on, when you start KeePass2, it will load this plugin and show the KeePass icon at the tray bar. I tested it on Xubuntu 14 and it works flawlessly. All credit goes to this guy: http://sourceforge.net/u/dlech27/profile/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, I have switched to LastPass in the meantime ;)

Comment: Working also on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I was able to manually add the `wily` version of that PPA to install the plugin on Debian Jessie.

Comment: There is also `keepass2-plugin-tray-icon` which is probably better suited to XFCE than the Application Indicator plugin (Application Indicators are mainly a Unity desktop thing.)